# Firefox sync via dropbox

Tags: firefox, sync, dropbox, bookmarks

This is my problem:

Firefox sync is totaly unusable, mostly because of this: [Bug 787500](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=787500) and because it often syncs some bookmarks wrong. (I have noticed it restoring and dublicating the deleted ones constantly)

The only solution I've found is to make a Symbolic links of my firefox profiles to dropbox both on my PC and laptop, but there are some cons here as well:

1. Persistent browser writing into cache makes dropbox to sync all the
   time
2. I have to close firefox on my laptop, wait for sync to finish,
   and wait to sync again before launching firefox on my pc

Finally, the questions:

1. Do you think this non-stop syncing is okay for dropbox?
2. Can anyone suggest a better solution?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It is okay for Dropbox.

You can try using Selective Sync and syncing the Cache folder.

Alternative is to use Firefox Portable. Still, I would exclude syncing the Cache folder.